# Convert Object which has value an Array to another Array of Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, reduce

I have this kind of object:

```
{
    "John":[
        {
            "address":"xxx1",
            "city":"yyy1"
        },
        {
            "address":"xxx2",
            "city":"yyy2"
        }
        
    ],
    
    "Doe":[
        {
            "address":"aaaa1",
            "city":"aaa1"
        }
        
    ],

    "Smith":[
        {
            "address":"bbb1",
            "city":"bbb1"
        }
    ],

}
```

What I try to achieve is to reduce this object so it look like this:

```
[
{
    "name":"John",
    "address":"xxx1",
    "city":"yyy1"
},
{
    "name":"John",
    "address":"xxx2",
    "city":"yyy2"
},
{
    "name":"Doe",
    "address":"aaaa1",
    "city":"aaaa1"
},
{
    "name":"Smith",
    "address":"bbb1",
    "city":"bbb1"
}
]
```

But I'm sure that the same thing can be done somehow by using the ES6 `array.reduce`. Can you help me? I looked at JS (ES6): Reduce array based on object attribute but I can't figure it out.

```
const modifiedData = Object.entries(data).reduce(function (acc, [key,value]) {
      const personName = key;
      return [
        ...acc,
        {
          Agent: personName ,
          adress: value.adress

        },
      ];
    }, []);
```

Comment: Use `.flatMap()` to iterate over the result of `Object.entries()` and in the callback use `.map()` to create new objects with the given properties + the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```js
const obj = {
  John: [
    {
      address: "xxx1",
      city: "yyy1",
    },
    {
      address: "xxx2",
      city: "yyy2",
    },
  ],

  Doe: [
    {
      address: "aaaa1",
      city: "aaa1",
    },
  ],

  Smith: [
    {
      address: "bbb1",
      city: "bbb1",
    },
  ],
};

const result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, arr]) => {
  const collection = arr.map((a) => ({ name: key, ...a }));
  acc = [...acc, ...collection];
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log( result );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using `Array.prototype.reduce`, you can do something like this:

```js
const input = {
  "John": [{
      "address": "xxx1",
      "city": "yyy1"
    },
    {
      "address": "xxx2",
      "city": "yyy2"
    }

  ],
  "Doe": [{
      "address": "aaaa1",
      "city": "aaa1"
    }

  ],
  "Smith": [{
    "address": "bbb1",
    "city": "bbb1"
  }],
}

// 1. Using Object.keys()
const output1 = Object.keys(input).reduce((acc, person) => {
  input[person].forEach(item => {
    acc.push({ name: person, ...item })
  })
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log('output1:', output1)

// 2. Using Object.entries()
const output2 = Object.entries(input).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  value.forEach(item => {
    acc.push({ name: key, ...item })
  });
  return acc;
}, [])
console.log('output2:', output2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way like this.

```js
const data = {"John":[{"address":"xxx1","city":"yyy1"},{"address":"xxx2","city":"yyy2"}],"Doe":[{"address":"aaaa1","city":"aaa1"}],"Smith":[{"address":"bbb1","city":"bbb1"}],};;

const result = Object.entries(data).flatMap(([key, values]) => 
                                   values.map(o => ({name: key, ...o})));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Nguyen, Your solution is good too, but decpk's solution was first and it fits my needs so I accepted his answer. Thanks!